# Removing Extranet zone from Sharepoint site

Tags: 2007, administration, alternate-access-mapping, web-application-zones

Right now my Sharepoint site has two zones, Default and Extranet. Because of this we are experiencing difficulties with our client integration. I want to just unify the zones (make it all "Default" zone) but the STSADM tool is *not* having it. I tried to execute this command to remove the Extranet zone to no avail while the site was shut down:

```
An object in the SharePoint administrative framework, "SPAlternateUrlCollection
Name=SharePoint - 80 Parent=SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config_fed16ac9-3be3-403a-8f6
a-7412e54509cc", could not be deleted because other objects depend on it.  Updat
e all of these dependants to point to null or different objects and retry this o
peration.  The dependant objects are as follows:
SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - 80 Parent=SPWebService
```

I just want to get rid of the extranet zone so I have one zone, Default. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RichRoss Please only use the [tag:2007] tag for questions **completely specific to that version** (i.e. there is no way it could apply to any other version). This helps to attract more attention to the question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines. Thank you for your attempt to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Zones are just markers.  You can easily remove them from via CA under AAM (Alternate Access Mappings, just clear out everything but what resides in the default zone.  You could just as easily leave everything as is and just allow access to the default zone.

You can do this via deletezoneurl in STSADM ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288187(office.12).aspx )

Now, if have have extended your webapp, and utilize the AAM to access that, you should also remove the IIS entry, this is also done in CA via the "Remove SharePoint site from IIS" (just make sure you select the extended site not the one you are using"

You can do this with the unextendvs command ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262863(office.12).aspx )

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the Central Administration and removed the Zone from the Web Application.  STSADM is nice for many things, but the CA also makes some things easier.  Unless you are not using SP 2010.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using SP 07

Comment: Might want to note that in the Question as that is a different procedure....